# Update of column happens even though I don't want it to happen

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I've got a case statement:

```
UPDATE
   Answer
SET
   AnswerID = @AnswerID,
   AnsweredBy = CASE WHEN LEN(@AnsweredBy) > 0 THEN @AnsweredBy END
```

Even when `@AnsweredBy` is `NULL` it still sets the `AnsweredBy` column to null.

I've tried to test for null as well by doing this:

```
 UPDATE
    Answer
 SET
    AnswerID = @AnswerID,
    AnsweredBy = CASE WHEN @AnsweredBy IS NOT NULL THEN @AnsweredBy END
```

Meaning I do not want to update the `answeredby` column unless there is a value.

Even in my C# code I do not pass a value to my stored procedure:

```
if (answeredBy.Length > 0)
   cmdSelect.Parameters.Add("@AnsweredBy", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = answeredBy;
```

unless there is a value. And in my sproc I default that column variable to null:

```
@RunoffAnswerID bigint,
@AnswerID varchar(3)=NULL,
@AnsweredBy varchar(50)=NULL,
```

So my question is how do I perform the rest of my updates, because there are about 5-10 more columns but only update the `answeredby` if there is a value in `@AnsweredBy`?

Comment: Your statement is updating every single record.  Is that correct, or should it only be updating a single record?  If you don't want ***every*** record to be updated, you need a `WHERE` clause...

Comment: Your problem is that you don't tell it what to do if the case stament action is not met, so it nulls out the value. Either  answer below will work but I wanted to explain why yours did not.

Comment: Dems I didnt post my entire query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SET AnsweredBy = ISNULL(@AnsweredBy, AnsweredBy)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE 
    Answer 
SET 
    AnswerID = @AnswerID, 
    AnsweredBy = CASE WHEN LEN(@AnsweredBy) > 0 THEN @AnsweredBy ELSE AnsweredBy END
```